# How to get the compounded value from this javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I will be making a CI calculator, here is a compounded interest formula that i have obtained: Total Amount = `P(1+(R/100))n`

Some details on each statement above:

> CI = Compound Interest,   P = Principal or Sum of amount,   R = % Rate
>   per annum,   n = Time Span in years,   Total Amount = P +
>   CI

But i can't figure it out how to get the compounded value?

It should output Compounded value: 1691.13

```
var typ = 1;
var r = 6; // % Rate per annum
var p = 5000; // Principal or Sum of amount
var n = 5; // Time Span in years

var result = Math.pow(1 + ((r/typ)/100), typ * n);
var c = p * result; 
var e = c; // Output is 6691.13, Compounded value: 1691.13

alert(e);
```

I expect the output to be 1691.13

Comment: The compounded value is c - p. In e you have the principal amount + interest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `c` variable will contain the *full amount* after interest has been accrued, like in a bank account - it'll contain the initial amount *and* the accrued amount. Subtract the initial value from it to get only the accrued amount. Using descriptive variable names will probably make things a lot more clear:

```js
var typ = 1;
var annualInterest = 6; // % Rate per annum
var initialAmount = 5000; // Principal or Sum of amount
var years = 5; // Time Span in years

var multiplier = Math.pow(1 + ((annualInterest/typ)/100), typ * years);
const finalAmount = initialAmount * multiplier; 
const earnedInterest = (finalAmount - initialAmount).toFixed(2);
console.log(earnedInterest);
```

You can also subtract 1 from the multiplier to obtain the earned interest only, rather than subtracting the `initialAmount` afterwards:

```js
var typ = 1;
var annualInterest = 6; // % Rate per annum
var initialAmount = 5000; // Principal or Sum of amount
var years = 5; // Time Span in years

var multiplier = Math.pow(1 + ((annualInterest/typ)/100), typ * years) - 1;
const earnedInterest = (initialAmount * multiplier).toFixed(2);
console.log(earnedInterest);
```

You can also use `toFixed(2)` to take only 2 decimal places.

Comment: My friend told me that the output should be converted to decimal like: (finalAmount - initialAmount)*100/100, is this similar with toFixed?

Comment: Yes, `toFixed` rounds the number to the passed number of decimal places

Answer (score 0):

Your `c` varaible is the `Total Amount`
now, you can use your equation: `Total Amount = P + CI`

it make: `CI = Total Amount - P`
So `6691.13 - 5000 = 1691.13`